# What is the logical 'not' in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, prolog-dif

The problem that I face, is a bit trivial.
I want to use logical not in Prolog, but it seems that `not/1` is not the thing that I want:

```
course(ai).
course(pl).
course(os).

have(X,Y) :- course(X),course(Y),not(X = Y).
```

I query:

```
have(X,Y), write(X-Y), nl , fail.
```

And I do not get the result I want :(

Comment: what is the result that you want?

Comment: what is the result that you got would also be nice for question readability btw

Comment: I want it to print for me combinations of the course names, where the two are not equal, I mean: ai-pl   ai-os   pl-ai   pl-os   os-ai   os-pl

Comment: @MasoodDelfarah That's exactly what it does, isn't it?

Comment: @sepp2k no I get error: uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,not/1),have/2) using gnu prolog

Comment: then use \+ (X = Y) or X \= Y instead.

Answer (score 42):

In place of `not(X = Y)` you need to write `\+ X = Y` or `X \= Y`. But consider to use `dif(X,Y)` instead. `dif/2` is present in B, SWI, YAP, SICStus. To see the difference:

```
?- X = b, dif(a, X).
   X = b.
?- X = b, \+ a = X.
   X = b.
```

So up to now everything seems to be fine.  But what, if we simply
exchange the order of the two goals?

```
?- \+ a = X, X = b.
   false. 
?- dif(a, X), X = b.
   X = b.
```

`(\+)/1` now gives us a different result, because there is an answer
for `a = X`, the goal `\+ a = X` will fail.

`(\+)/1` is thus not negation, but means *not provable at this point
in time*.

[A safe approximation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20238931/772868) of `dif/2` is possible in ISO Prolog, too.

Comment: Just for completeness' sake, this "sound negation" is also available in ECLiPSe, using `~/2` or `~=/2`, and the equivalent queries would be `?- ~(a=X), X=b.` or `?- a~=X, X=b.`

Comment: Is there any other Prolog other than ECLiPSe which uses `(~=)/2` for `dif/2`? From memory, Mu- and Nu-Prolog used to have it.

Answer (score 15):

In both SWI-Prolog and GNU Prolog, the following should work:

```
have(X, Y) :- course(X), course(Y), X \= Y.
```

In SWI-Prolog, you can also use `dif/2`, which can be more convenient since you can use it earlier in the predicate:

```
have(X, Y) :- dif(X, Y), course(X), course(Y).
```

Comment: anyway, OP tagged swi-pl without checking on swi I guess since his version works on swi, even if not/1 is deprecated there.

Answer (score 6):

As an adjunct to the answer by user "false" above, i.e.

"In place of not(X = Y) you need to write \+ X = Y,"

This might give the impression that:

a. "not" and "\+" are different things

b. The \+ will work whereas the not will, err, not.

My understanding is that "not" and "\+" are equivalent, but that \+ is preferred in modern Prolog programs, because it conveys a sense that is more intuitive. Specifically, whereas "not" might suggest "is not true" to the unwary coder, "\+" suggests "is not provable" which is much closer to the truth of what that operation is really saying. In Prolog, the "not" is an example of "negation as failure", but it is felt that \+ will make it clearer to the programmer just what precisely is being asserted in any given rule. So you CAN use "not" (most PL implementations keep it for backwards-compatibility) but to be an idiomatic modern PL programmer, you probably should prefer to use \+.

Answer (score 5):

Reading Samuel Kamin's [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201068249) on chapter 8, prolog, I found this solution that also fits here and explains how to use the `cut`:

> The cut is a way of giving the programmer additional control over the computation by allowing him to indicate places where backtracking is impermissible. Specifically, the cut is written as an exclamation mark (!) occurring as a goal in the right-hand side of a clause such as:

```
G :- H, !, R.
```

> Suppose this clause is chosen to satisfy a goal **g** with which G [unifies](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse5). An attempt is made to satisfy H. If successful, R is proven. **If the proof of R succeeds, then g is proven**; in this case, the cut has no part to play. **If, however, the proof of R fails**, rather than backtrack and try to re-prove H, **the presence of the cut causes the goal g to fail immediately**; this occurs even if there are further clauses that might apply to g. An example is the definition of **not-equals**:

```
equals(X, X).
not-equals(X, Y) :- equals(X, Y), !, fail.
not-equals(X, Y).
```

`not-equals(X, Y)` should succeed if X is not equal to Y, and fail if it is; X and Y should be bound to [ground expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_expression) (i.e. have no free variables) when attempting to satisfy this goal.

Comment: Here is a free online resource for cut and negation: [http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlch10](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlch10)

Answer (score 1):

Like you said, OP, this is trivial.

Try

```
course(ai).
course(pl).
course(os).

have(X,Y) :- course(X), course(Y), X \== Y).
```

That should fix your predicate.

Looking one step ahead though, mathematically phrasing, you are probably looking for the solution to (n **C** 2) as opposed to (n **P** 2) which your predicate currently provides—combination instead of permutation, choice of selection as opposed to arrangements of choices of selection. This is what I think.

If this is what you want, I would suggest you try

```
course(ai).
course(pl).
course(os).

have(X,Y) :- course(X), course(Y), X @< Y).
```

Which would prevent duplicate reversed results.

`@<` means atomically less than. `<` is for integers, `@<` is for atoms.