# How to negate in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm new to PROLOG and am at the very beginning of the exercises on [this page](https://sites.google.com/site/prologsite/prolog-course/a-first-glimpse). Given the rules parent(X, Y) and male(X), I'm trying to define a rule mother(X, Y) as

```
mother(X, Y) :-
    not(male(X)),
    parent(X, Y).
```

However, in GNU Prolog I get the following error:

```
| ?- mother(lina, julia).
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,not/1),mother/2)
| ?-
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`\+/1` is the ISO Prolog predicate to "negate". Note that "negate" means here not provable at that point.

You can refer to [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523608/logical-not-in-prolog/8523825#8523825) by @false for more on the subject

Answer (score 14):

The solution is actually in the exercise file on that page:

```
female(X) :- \+ male(X).
```

As @Mog said, negation is the unary `\+` operator.