# Use a rule if a fact doesn't exist in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm new to prolog.
The idea of my project is to say "The room X is free if none is a guest of X, while X is taken if a family lives in X".
I use a predicate

```
guest(FamilySurname,RoomTaken)
```

So this mean that a family has taken that room.

```
taken(X) :- guest(_,X).
```

So if a family lives in room X, then X is taken.

My problem is how could i say that the room X is free? I should use a kind of NOT, like:

```
free(X) :- "NOT EXIST" guest(_,X).
```

How could i translate that "NOT EXIST" in prolog?
I have tried with ! but it doesn't work properly... maybe I'm placing it in the wrong way.

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the first answer does not seem to be a solution, i.e. the query `?- free(X)` will not give an answer, where as the query `?- free(foo)` will be successful. One needs to consider [query floundering in Prolog](http://soft.vub.ac.be/~cderoove/declarative_programming/decprog3_sld_cut_naf.pdf)  into account, i.e. all variables

Consider the following code in which two alternatives for presenting the `free` predicate.

```
 room(123).
 room(124).
 guest(albert, 123).

 taken(Room) :- guest(_, Room).

 free2(Room) :- room(Room),
                \+ taken(Room).

 free(Room) :- room(Room),
               forall(guest(_, RoomTaken),
                      RoomTaken \= Room).
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the following code:

```
taken(X, Y) :- guest(Y,X).
free(X) :- \+ guest(_,X).
```

I made the a little change to taken, now it shows you who is on that room.

```
guest(albert, 123).

?- taken(123, R).

R = albert.
```

And the free() predicate it's pretty straightforward, I used the negation operator, you can check [How to negate in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141600/how-to-negate-in-prolog)