# Negation in prolog

Tags: prolog

Well i'm just wondering why does it work, where prolog loose variable.

```
?- \+ \+ member(X,[a]),X=b.
X=b.
```

Where X=a. automagicly vanished.

Comment: See [this great answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523608/logical-not-in-prolog/8523825#8523825) by false for some precisions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\+/1` is not "not" in the logical sense, but is implemented through "negation as failure". That means, `\+ Goal` succeeds iff `Goal` fails.

Think of `\+/1` as being implemented as:

```
\+(Goal) :- Goal -> fail ; true.
```

As you can see, in both cases can no variable in `Goal` become bound. In the "if" branch, any binding will be undone by backtracking, and in the "else" branch, no variable will have been become bound anyway.

In your example, `member(X,[a]` succeeds by binding `X` to `a`. This will have `\+ member(X,[a])` fail, and so `\+\+ member(X,[a])` succeeds because of this failure. Due to the intermediate failure, `X` will not be bound to `a`.

Answer (score 1):

the `(\+)/1` operator in prolog is *supposed* to stand for not provable but corresponds to the older `(not)/1` operator. So basically what you are doing here is:

```
not not member(X, [a]), X = b.
```

**EDIT**

If `X` is a list that contains `a`, the double negation of `member(X, [a])` will have the same result as `member(X, [a])` without any negations. `X = b`, just binds `b` to the list `X`.

Also [here is a link](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/prologdict.html) I had bookmarked that has a list of all Prolog predicates and their meanings.

Hope this helps

Comment: The way you phrase things is very confusing to me. I don't understand your answer (especially the part under the code formatted block).

Comment: I just re-read what I posted and I can see why you are confused. Basically the member function returns true or false, true if a is in X, false if a is not in X. Saying `not not member(X, [a])` is the same as saying `member(X, [a])` because the not operators cancel out.

Comment: that is false, obviously here you can't replace `not not member(X, [a])` with `member(X, [a])` precisely because the unification will take place in the second case and not in the first, hence the general result that will be false in the first case, and `X = b.` in the second.

Comment: but let aside the fact that this is true or false, you should edit your answer to make it more understandable so that we can comment about it in a clearer manner! :p

Comment: @Mog I edited above to make the post clearer. At least in the sense that this is what _I_ think is going on with the `\+ \+` ops. I may be wrong.

Comment: Thanks, but as you can see, `?- member(X, [a]), X = b.` returns `false.` while `?- \+ \+ member(X, [a]), X = b.` returns `X = b.`. That's precisely the object of this question (the fact that those two queries are NOT equivalent). see twinterer's answer for an explanation of the `(\+)/1` operator. BTW, if you have to precise the "not provable" description, you should go for "not provable at this point in time" instead of "not". Just my .02!