# alias `(not)/1` in prolog

Tags: prolog, alias, negation

I have recieved a piece of code for an assignment called exShell. In it, the code uses `(not)/1` for negation, I have currently replaced all instances with `(\+)/1` but I was wondering why that would be there in the first place. Is it possible to alias `(\+)/1` with `(not)/1` or is that a convention of cprolog or some other prolog compiler (for instance cprolog).

```
solve(not A, C, Rules, (not Proof, C), T, Ask) :- !,
    T1 is -1 * T,
    solve(A, C1, Rules, Proof, T1, Ask),
    C is -1 * C1.
```

This is an example of it being used.

Comment: `(not)/1` and `(\+)/1` are already aliases. Only, `(not)/1` is deprecated while `(\+)/1` isn't. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8523825/1027951) for more explanations. the `+` stands for provable and the antislash for not actually, meaning "not provable", which is more correct than "not".

Comment: @Mog: I find your comment at least as much explicative as the linked answer...

Comment: actually in the program not is used as such 'not A' there is no brackets to the function, so wouldn't this be 'not/0'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like `not` here is a unary operator, declared e.g. with `op(500,fy,not)`, so is used as symbolic data which the `solve/6` predicate is processing. E.g.,

```
?- op(500,fy,not).

Yes
?- write( not 3).
not 3

Yes
?- write_canonical( not 3).
not(3)

Yes
?- not 3 =.. X .

X = [not, 3] 

Yes
?-
```

Comment: So why then is is breaking on the compiler? Also, these commands all work in my listener, but any use of not on a variable or predicate throws an error, I don't understand what you mean by symbolic data.

Comment: any Prolog compound term is a symbolic data. It is just data, not a command or anything. The term `not(3)` has functor `not` and argument `3`. You inspect any compound term with `arg` or `=..` etc. From what you've shown there is a predicate `solve` defined somewhere that you use. It is supposed to handle terms of form `not(X)` apparently. Or so it looks like, from what you've posted. If you "use `not` on a variable" you rely on Prolog to handle it; but you show us some predicate `solve` that's handling it. I.e. not by itself in Prolog, but through the predicate `solve`.

Comment: so just for clarification and to make sure I'm following this, `not(x)` is logically equivalent to `\+`, in the case of this program `not` is causing a error because it's being handled improperly in the implementation. From a previous post it sounds like `not` is depreciated.
 Sorry I'm very new to prolog.

Comment: it depends, where. in what you've shown, not, it is not equivalent to anything by itself, it's just a piece of data - a compound term with a functor name `not` and one argument. It doesn't have a meaning by itself - or maybe it has, depending on the compiler. SWI Prolog e.g. does handle goals of the form `not(X)`, equivalently to how it handles `\+(X)`. What Prolog are you using and what error message do you get? --- but in the code you've shown it could've been named *anything*. Name by itself doesn't matter, only how is it handled matters - in that case, by that predicate, `solve`.

Comment: the predicate name `not` is deprecated because it is misleading. In Prolog, its semantics is "can't be proven that ...". So `\+(X)` is used instead.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, in this piece of code it `not` could really be name anything. It's just a defined op, and is sensitive to how it's previously been define. I'm using was using gprolog, and was getting a predicate not existing error, I recopied the code to test without the find replace change, and now it's compiling fine. I guess I must have copied it wrong. I'm sorry waisting your time, but I do appreciate the help and it did make me understand the language more.