# Difference between X\=Y and dif(X,Y)

Tags: prolog, prolog-dif

What is the difference between this:

```
X \= Y
```

and this piece of code:

```
dif(X, Y)
```

I thought that they should behave the same, but they do not. Here's the example:

```
n_puta(L, N, X) :- nputa(L, N, 0, X).
nputa([], N, C, _) :- N = C.
nputa([G|R], N, C, X) :- G = X, nputa(R, N, Y, X), C is Y - 1.
nputa([G|R], N, C, X) :- dif(G,X), nputa(R, N, C, X).
```

And here are some calls:

```
?- n_puta([a,a,b,b,b], 2, X).
X = a ;
false.

?- n_puta([a,a,b,a,b,b], 3, X).
X = a ;
X = b ;
false.
```

X should be the atom that occurs exactly N times in the list L. If I replace `dif(G, X)` with `G \= X`, I don't get the expected result. Can someone tell me what is the difference between these two operators? Can I use anything else except `dif(G, X)`?

This example works prefectly in SWI-Prolog, but doesn't work in Amzi! Prolog.

Comment: I had a similar question that got plenty of useful answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757261/using-or-dif?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dif/2` and `(\=)/2` are the same as long as their arguments are ground. But only `dif/2` is a pure relation that works correctly also with variables and can be used in all directions. Your example clearly shows that you should use `dif/2` in this case, because you use your predicate not only to test, but also to generate solutions. The most widely used Prolog systems all provide `dif/2`.