# Prolog: inequality operator

Tags: prolog, prolog-dif

I am using SICStus Prolog and have a set of facts:

```
student('John Henry', 'Maths').
student('Jim Henry', 'Maths').
student('John Alan', 'Maths').
student('Alan Smith', 'Computing').
student('Gary Henry', 'Maths').
```

I want to get the shared subject of two students where both students are different, so I got:

```
sharedSubject(S1, S2, Sub) :- S1 \== S2, student(S1, Sub), student(S2, Sub).
```

However, when I enter:

```
sharedSubject('John Henry', F, E).
```

I get `F = 'John Henry'`. Can someone point out where I am going wrong and what I need to do? Thanks.

Comment: Both good answers. I picked Paulo's one because of the explanation. I did not think about the instantiation before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must move the `S1 \== S2` goal to the end as. If you call your `sharedSubject/3` predicate with the second argument not instantiated, as in your `sharedSubject('John Henry', F, E)`, the `S1 \== S2` goal will always be true:

```
?- 'John Henry' \== S2.
true.
```

Also:

```
?- S1 \== S2.
true.
```

See the documentation of the standard `(\==)/2` built-in predicate in your Prolog system documentation. In a nutshell, unless you want to test if two variables are the same, be sure that both arguments are instantiated when calling this term **equality** predicate.

Answer (score 9):

Use `dif/2` instead, or set the `\==` at the end of the rule - which is not as safe as `dif/2`. See also:

[Difference between X\=Y and dif(X,Y)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560058/difference-between-x-y-and-difx-y?lq=1)

[What is the logical 'not' in Prolog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523608/logical-not-in-prolog/8523825#8523825)

[Using \==/2 or dif/2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757261/using-or-dif?lq=1)