# Why does this prolog program returns false?

Tags: prolog, prolog-dif

```
woman(lisa).
woman(maggie).

parents(lisa  , homer, marge).
parents(maggie, homer, marge).

sister(X, Y) :-
   X \= Y,
   woman(X),
   parents(X, P, M),
   parents(Y, P, M).
```

When I ran the following query, I *did not expect failure* (but got it nonetheless).

```
?- sister(lisa, X).
false.                         % expected result: X = maggie
```

Why am I seeing this behavior?

Comment: `(\=)/2` is not a pure logical relation. Use the pure predicate `dif/2` instead. The problem with `(\=)/2` in a nutshell: `?- X \= Y, X = a, Y = b.` yields **false**, but `X = a, Y = b, X \= Y` **succeeds**.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `sister(X,Y)` says that `Y` is a sister of `X`, you want `woman(Y)`, not `woman(X)`.

Re-arranging the rule makes it work ([demo](http://ideone.com/mvxonw)):

```
sister(X, Y):-
  woman(Y),
  parents(X, P, M),
  parents(Y, P, M),
  X \= Y.
```

The important thing in this re-arrangement is that the `X \= Y` term is moved to a point after both `X` and `Y` have been *bound* - `X` is given to the rule as input, and `Y` is bound through participation in `woman(Y)`.

Comment: @ManuelW. It does not have to be the last one, it could be the second one (right after `woman(Y)` - [demo](http://ideone.com/P8v8Lg)). The important thing is that `Y` needs to be *bound* before the inequality check.

Answer (score 1):

Stay pure! How? Use [prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif) for expressing term inequality!

```
sister(X, Y) :-
   dif(X, Y),
   woman(X),
   parents(X, P, M),
   parents(Y, P, M).
```

Sample query:

```
?- sister(lisa, X).
X = maggie.
```

---

For more on `dif/2` see also:

- [Prolog: inequality operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20010215/4609915)
- [Difference between X\=Y and dif(X,Y)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560058/difference-between-x-y-and-difx-y?lq=1)
- [What is the logical 'not' in Prolog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523608/logical-not-in-prolog/8523825#8523825)
- [Using \==/2 or dif/2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757261/using-or-dif?lq=1)