# prolog doesn't give me a solution when one exists

Tags: prolog, prolog-dif, logical-purity

I am working through *Seven Languages in Seven Weeks*, but there is something I don't understand about prolog.  I have the following program (based on their wallace and grommit program):

```
/* teams.pl */

onTeam(a, aTeam).
onTeam(b, aTeam).
onTeam(b, superTeam).
onTeam(c, superTeam).

teamMate(X, Y) :- \+(X = Y), onTeam(X, Z), onTeam(Y, Z).
```

and load it like this

```
?- ['teams.pl'].
true.
```

but it doesn't give me any solutions to the following

```
?- teamMate(a, X).
false.
```

it can solve simpler stuff (which is shown in the book):

```
?- onTeam(b, X).
X = aTeam ;
X = superTeam.
```

and there are solutions:

```
?- teamMate(a, b).
true ;
false.
```

What am I missing?  I have tried with both gnu prolog and swipl.

...AND THERE IS MORE...

when you move the "can't be your own teammate" restriction to then end:

```
/* teams.pl */

onTeam(a, aTeam).
onTeam(b, aTeam).
onTeam(b, superTeam).
onTeam(c, superTeam).

teamMate(X, Y) :- onTeam(X, Z), onTeam(Y, Z), \+(X = Y).
```

it gives me the solutions I would expect:

```
?- ['teams.pl'].
true.

?- teamMate(a, X).
X = b.

?- teamMate(b, X).
X = a ;
X = c.
```

What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [answer by mat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39815328/1812457) gives you some high-level considerations and a solution. My answer is a more about the underlying reasons, which might or might not be interesting to you.

(By the way, while learning Prolog, I asked pretty much [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757261/using-or-dif) and got a [very similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13759359/1812457) by the same user. Great.)

### The proof tree

You have a question:

> Are two players team mates?

To get an answer from Prolog, you formulate a query:

```
?- team_mate(X, Y).
```

where both X and Y can be free variables or bound.

Based on your database of predicates (facts and rules), Prolog tries to *find a proof* and gives you solutions. Prolog [searches for a proof by doing a depth-first traversal of a proof tree](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse6).

In your first implementation, `\+ (X = Y)` comes before anything else, so it at the root node of the tree, and will be evaluated before the following goals. And if either `X` or `Y` is a free variable, `X = Y` **must succeed**, which means that `\+ (X = Y)` **must fail**. So the query **must fail**.

On the other hand, if either `X` or `Y` is a free variable, [`dif(X, Y)`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=dif/2) **will succeed**, but a later attempt to unify them with each other **must fail**. At that point, Prolog will have to look for a proof down another branch of the proof tree, if there are any left.

(With the proof tree in mind, try to figure out a way of implementing `dif/2`: do you think it is possible without either a) adding some kind of state to the arguments of `dif/2` or b) changing the resolution strategy?)

And finally, if you put `\+ (X = Y)` at the very end, and take care that both `X` and `Y` are ground by the time it is evaluated, then the unification becomes more like a simple comparison, and it **can fail**, so that the negation **can succeed**.

Answer (score 7):

You have made a very good observation! In fact, the situation is even worse, because even the *most general* query *fails*:

```
?- teamMate(X, Y).
false.
```

Declaratively, this means "there are no solutions whatsoever", which is obviously **wrong** and not how we expect relations to behave: If there are solutions, then *more general* queries *must not fail*.

The reason you get this strange and logically incorrect behaviour is that `(\+)/1` is only sound if its arguments are **sufficiently instantiated**.

To express **disequality** of terms in a more general way, which works correctly *no matter if the arguments are instantiated or not*, use **`dif/2`**, or, if your Prolog system does not provide it, the safe approximation `iso_dif/2` which you can find in the **[prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif)** tag.

For example, in your case (`note_that_I_am_using_underscores_for_readability` instead of `tuckingTheNamesTogetherWhichMakesThemHarderToRead`):

```
team_mate(X, Y) :- dif(X, Y), on_team(X, Z), on_team(Y, Z).
```

Your query now works exactly as expected:

```
?- team_mate(a, X).
X = b.
```

The most general query of course also works correctly:

```
?- team_mate(X, Y).
X = a,
Y = b ;
X = b,
Y = a ;
X = b,
Y = c ;
etc.
```

Thus, using `dif/2` to express disequality preserves **[logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity)** of your relations: The system now no longer simply says `false` *even though there are solutions*. Instead, you get the answer you expect! Note that, in contrast to before, this also works *no matter where you place the call*!