# (SWI)Prolog: Order of sub-goals

Tags: prolog

I have two, slightly different, implementations of a predicate, `unique_element/2`, in Prolog. The predicate succeeds when given an element `X` and a list `L`, the element `X` appears only once in the list. Below are the implementations and the results:

Implementation 1:

```
%%% unique_element/2
unique_element(Elem, [Elem|T]) :-
    not(member(Elem, T)). 
unique_element(Elem, [H|T]) :-
    member(Elem, T), 
    H\==Elem, 
    unique_element(Elem, T), 
    !.
```

Results:

```
?- unique_element(X, [a, a, b, c, c, b]). 
false.

?- unique_element(X, [a, b, c, c, b, d]).
X = a ;
X = d.
```

Implementation 2:

```
%%% unique_element/2
unique_element(Elem, [Elem|T]) :- 
    not(member(Elem, T)). 
unique_element(Elem, [H|T]) :-
    H\==Elem, 
    member(Elem, T), 
    unique_element(Elem, T), 
    !.
```

In case you didn't notice at first sight: `H\==Elem` and `member(Elem, T)` are flipped on the 2nd impl, rule 2.

Results:

```
?- unique_element(X, [a, a, b, c, c, b]).
X = a.

?- unique_element(X, [a, b, c, c, b, d]).
X = a ;
X = d.
```

Question: How does the order, in this case, affect the result? I realize that the order of the rules/facts/etc matters. The two specific rules that are flipped though, don't seem to be "connected" or affect each other somehow (e.g. a `cut` in the wrong place/order).

Note: We are talking about SWI-Prolog here.

Note 2: I am aware of, probably different and better implementations. My question here is about the order of sub-goals being changed.

Comment: Both versions incorrectly fail for `unique_element(X,[a,b,c]), X = c.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Read the documentation and figure out why:

```
?- X = a, X \== a.
false.

?- X \== a, X = a.
X = a.
```

---

I wonder why you stop so close from figuring it out yourself ;-)

There are too many ways to compare things in Prolog. At the very least, you have unification, which sometimes can compare, and sometimes does more; than you have equvalence, and its negation, the one you are using. So what does it do:

```
?- a \== b. % two different ground terms
true.

?- a \== a. % the same ground term
false.
```

Now it gets interesting:

```
?- X \== a. % a free variable and a ground term
true.

?- X \== X. % the same free variable
false.

?- X \== Y. % two different free variables
true.
```

I would suggest that you do the following: figure out how `member/2` does its thing (does it use unification? equivalence? something else?) then replace whatever `member/2` is using in all the examples above and see if the results are any different.

And since you are trying to make sure that things are different, try out what `dif/2` does. As in:

```
?- dif(a, b).
```

or

```
?- dif(X, X).
```

or

```
?- dif(X, a).
```

and so on.

See also [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13757261/1812457): I think the answers are relevant to your question.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 9):

`H\==Elem` is testing for syntactic inequality at the point in time when the goal is executed. But later unification might make variables identical:

```
?- H\==Elem, H = Elem.
   H = Elem.

?- H\==Elem, H = Elem, H\==Elem.
   false.
```

So here we test if they are (syntactically) different, and then they are unified nevertheless and thus are no longer different. It is thus just a temporary test.

The goal `member(Elem, T)` on the other hand is true if that `Elem` is actually an element of `T`. Consider:

```
 ?- member(Elem, [X]).
    Elem = X.
```

Which can be read as

> (When) does it hold that `Elem` is an element of the list `[X]`?

and the answer is

> It holds under certain circumstances, namely when `Elem = X`.

If you now mix those different kinds of goals in your programs you get odd results that can only explained by inspecting your program in detail.

As a beginner, it is best to stick to the pure parts of Prolog only. In your case:

- use `dif/2` in place of `\==`
- do not use cuts - in your case it limits the number of answers to two. As in
  `unique_element(X, [a,b,c])`
- do not use `not/1` nor `(\+)/1`. It produces even more incorrectness. Consider `unique_element(a,[a,X]),X=b.` which incorrectly fails while `X=b,unique_element(a,[a,X])` correctly succeeds.

---

Here is a directly purified version of your program. There is still room for improvement!

```
non_member(_X, []).
non_member(X, [E|Es]) :-
   dif(X, E),
   non_member(X, Es).

unique_element(Elem, [Elem|T]) :- 
    non_member(Elem, T). 
unique_element(Elem, [H|T]) :-
    dif(H,Elem), 
     % member(Elem, T),          % makes unique_element(a,[b,a,a|Xs]) loop
    unique_element(Elem, T).

?- unique_element(a,[a,X]).
   dif(X, a)
;  false.              % superfluous

?- unique_element(X,[E1,E2,E3]).
   X = E1, dif(E1, E3), dif(E1, E2)
;  X = E2, dif(E2, E3), dif(E1, E2)
;  X = E3, dif(E2, E3), dif(E1, E3)
;  false.
```

Note how the last query reads?

> When is `X` a unique element of (any) list `[E1,E2,E3]`?

The answer is threefold. Considering one element after the other:

> `X` is `E1` but only if it is different to `E2` and `E3`

etc.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another possibility do define unique_element/2 using [if_/3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/6101159) and maplist/2:

```
:- use_module(library(apply)).

unique_element(Y,[X|Xs]) :-
   if_(Y=X,maplist(dif(Y),Xs),unique_element(Y,Xs)).
```

In contrast to @user27815's very elegant solution (+s(0)) this version does not build on clpfd (used by [tcount/3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29960878/6101159)). The example queries given by the OP work as expected:

```
   ?- unique_element(a,[a, a, b, c, c, b]).
no
   ?- unique_element(X,[a, b, c, c, b, d]).
X = a ? ;
X = d ? ;
no
```

The example provided by @false now succeeds without leaving a superfluous choicepoint:

```
   ?- unique_element(a,[a,X]).
dif(a,X)
```

The other more general query yields the same results:

```
   ?- unique_element(X,[E1,E2,E3]).
E1 = X,
dif(X,E3),
dif(X,E2) ? ;
E2 = X,
dif(X,E3),
dif(X,E1) ? ;
E3 = X,
dif(X,E2),
dif(X,E1) ? ;
no
```

Answer (score 4):

Can you not define unique_element like tcount [Prolog - count repetitions in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20484180/prolog-count-repetitions-in-list/29960878#29960878)

`unique_element(X, List):- tcount(=(X),List,1).`

Comment: Maybe add some interesting uses?