# What am I missing about equality and unification in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, prolog-dif

I'm working through Clocksin and Mellish to try and finally go beyond just dabbling in Prolog.  FWIW, I'm running SWI-Prolog:

> SWI-Prolog version 7.2.3 for x86_64-linux

Anyway, I implemented a diff/2 predicate as part of exercise 1.4.  The predicate is very simple:

```
diff(X,Y) :- X \== Y.
```

And it works when used in the sister_of predicate, like this:

```
sister_of(X,Y) :- 
    female(X),
    diff(X,Y),
    parents(X, Mum, Dad ),
    parents(Y, Mum, Dad ).
```

in that, assuming the necessary additional facts, doing this:

```
?- sister_of(alice,alice).
```

returns false as expected.  But here's the rub.  If I do this instead:

```
?- sister_of(alice, Who).
```

(again, given the additional facts necessary)
I get

> Who = edward ;
>
> Who = alice;
>
> false

Even though, as already shown, the sister_of predicate does not treat alice as her own sister.

On the other hand, if I use the SWI provided dif/2 predicate, then everything works the way I would naively expect.

Can anyone explain why this is happening this way, and why my diff implementation doesn't work the way I'm expecting, in the case where I ask for additional unifications from that query?

The entire source file I'm working with can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/mindcrime/d2f9bdad1f3ed7603d041c8f23ecc4f1)

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: See [**Using \==/2 or dif/2**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757261/using-2-or-dif-2/13792360).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you note, the problem stems from the interplay between equality (or rather, inequality) and unification. Observe that in your definition of `sister_of`, you first find a candidate value for `X`, *then* try to constrain `Y` to be different, but `Y` is still an uninstantiated logic variable and the check is always going to succeed, like `diff(alice, Y)` will. The following constraints, including the last one that gives a concrete value to `Y`, come too late.

In general, what you need to do is ensure that by the time you get to the inequality check all variables are instantiated. Negation is a non-logical feature of Prolog and therefore potentially dangerous, but checking whether two *ground terms* are not equal is safe.