# Setting some order for prolog expressions

Tags: prolog, prolog-dif

I've got a rule in my Prolog program called `blanket(X,Y)` which checks if X is in a certain kind of set of Y which consists of:

- Y's parents
- Y's children
- Y's coparents

I've defined it as follows :

```
blanket(Y,X) :- different(Y,X),parent(Y,X);child(Y,X);coparent(Y,X).
```

However, this doesn't work as I expect. It correctly identifies X's parents, children, and coparents (if any) but it lists itself as both a parent and a coparent, which I do not want. Is it possible to set some kind of order, so that the `different(Y,X)` evaluates first and independently? I tried something like : `different(Y,X),(parent(Y,X);child(Y,X);coparent(Y,X)).`, of course, but that yields a syntax error as I"m still quite unfamiliar with the language.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Here are the `child`, `different`, and `coparent` relations:

```
child(X,Y) :- parent(Y,X).

different(X,Y) :- not(X == Y).

coparent(Y,X) :- parent(Y,Z),parent(X,Z).
```

For completeness.

Comment: Use `dif/2` in place of `different/2`!

Comment: @false - Could you please clarify as to why I would need to do that?

Comment: [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8523825/772868). `dif/2` works always as expected!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
blanket(Y,X) :- different(Y,X), parent(Y,X).
blanket(Y,X) :- different(Y,X), child(Y,X).
blanket(Y,X) :- different(Y,X), coparent(Y,X).
```

Comment: That has the same effect, unfortunately!

Comment: Not sure what the question is then. Can you give an example of query that returns a wrong answer?

Comment: Actually, your definition of different is wrong. Try 
different(X,Y) :- X \= Y.

Comment: Although I had to revert to my old definition of `blanket` above, that works! Thank you very much. If it's not too much trouble, could you please clarify why `not(X == Y)` would not work?

Comment: `not(X==Y)` is true,  while `X\=Y` is false. The former checks whether X and Y are equal, the latter checks if they are unifiable. The choice of which one to use pretty much depends on what you want to do, but most of the time I use `X=Y` and `X\=Y`.

In your case, `not(X==Y)` is always true because the two variables are not unified with constants. The whole thing should work if you move different as you previously defined it after the other condition.

Answer (score 0):

The problen is your definition of coparent. It is the statement that allows return itself as a valid result.

I suggest you redefine it, by example as:

```
coparent(Y,X) :- parent(Y,Z),parent(X,Z), X \= Y.
```

in this way, you can simply:

```
blanket(Y,X) :-parent(Y,X);child(Y,X);coparent(Y,X).
```

Of course, you can keep definition of "coparent" and only modify blanket as:

```
blanket(Y,X) :-parent(Y,X);child(Y,X);(coparent(Y,X), X\=Y).
```