# How to check all conditions in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I am  trying to execute the following code where I want to check all conditions:-

```
w(X):-
    (     X=1 ->  
        write('Yes'),nl;
          X=1 ->  
        write('Yes'),nl;
          X=2 ->  
        write('No')).
```

I want it to write with X=1.

```
Yes
Yes
```

P.S. this is if-else, but I don't want if-else.

How can I achieve this, the code just returns the first true it finds?

Comment: Do you know what a failure driven loop is and other ways to implement it?

Comment: Of interest: switch statement with [fallthrough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Fallthrough)

Comment: Of interest: [Forall instead of failure-driven loops](https://riptutorial.com/prolog/example/19554/forall-instead-of-failure-driven-loops)

Comment: Of interest: [forall/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=forall/2)

Comment: Of interest: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19383448/1243762) related to double negation.