# Why does prolog don't give all results, when I place the equality-comparision at the beginning?

Tags: prolog

Currently I'm exercising the Prolog chapter of seven languages in seven weeks. I tried to change the coloring example, in order to not write down every valid color combination.

```
different(red, green).
different(green, red).
different(red, blue).
different(blue, red).
different(blue, green).
different(green, blue).

coloring(A, M, G, T, F) :-
    different(M, T),
    different(M, A),
    different(A, T),
    different(A, M),
    different(A, G),
    different(A, F),
    different(G, F),
    different(G, T).
```

I changed the file to make different a <s>function</s>predicate:

```
color(red).
color(blue).
color(green).

different(X, Y) :- color(X), color(Y), \+(X=Y).
different_fail(X, Y) :- \+(X=Y), color(X), color(Y).

coloring(A, M, G, T, F) :-
    different(M, T),
    different(M, A),
    different(A, T),
    different(A, M),
    different(A, G),
    different(A, F),
    different(G, F),
    different(G, T).
```

What I don't get is that `different` gives me all combinations of different colors, but `different_fail` does only check if they are really different.

```
GNU Prolog 1.4.5 (32 bits)
Compiled Feb 23 2015, 08:36:31 with gcc
By Daniel Diaz
Copyright (C) 1999-2015 Daniel Diaz
| ?- ['color'].             
compiling /home/rudi/7langs/prolog/color.pl for byte code...
/home/rudi/7langs/prolog/color.pl compiled, 17 lines read - 2206 bytes written, 7 ms
| ?- different(red, red).   

no
| ?- different(red, blue).

yes
| ?- different_fail(red, red). 

no
| ?- different_fail(red, blue).
```

Up to here everything works as expected.

```
yes
| ?- different(red, A).        

A = blue ? ;

A = green

yes
| ?- different_fail(red, A).

no
```

But here I would expect that `different_fail` yields the exact results as `different`.

What is the difference in these functions, which cause my `different_fail` to fail?

Comment: Just to point out, like CapelliC has said (but Mat has not!) that `=` does **not** mean equality-comparison. A bit closer to what you need is `==` (see the documentation of your Prolog). For `\+ A == B` you can also write `A \== B`.

Comment: Just to point out (which nobody else has yet said!): Instead of "functions", you should write "predicates".

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8523825/772868)

Answer (score 2):

To declaratively express that two terms be different, use the `dif/2` constraint, which is available in SICStus Prolog, SWI-Prolog, YAP and several others.

If you write `different_colors/2` like this:

```
different_colors(X, Y) :- dif(X,Y), color(X), color(Y).
```

then everything will work exactly as you expect it, no matter in which order you place the goals.

The reason it currently fails is that `\+/1` only means *not provable at this time*. It is not true negation in the declarative sense. Therefore, we have:

```
?- \+ X = Y, X = a, Y = b.
false.
```

but if we simply exchange the goals by commutativity of conjunction:

```
?- X = a, Y = b, \+ X = Y.
X = a,
Y = b.
```

In contrast, `dif/2` works correctly in both cases, and I highly recommend you use it instead:

```
?- dif(X, Y), X = a, Y = b.
X = a,
Y = b.

?- X = a, Y = b, dif(X, Y).
X = a,
Y = b.
```

Comment: You are missing something important in your answer, namely, that `=` means unification, which is arguably not what OP is calling "equality-comparison".

Comment: There are several additional things wrong with OP's description (for example the use of "function" instead of "predicate", "combination" instead of "permutation" etc.). However, the *core problems* are missing knowledge of `dif/2` to express syntactic disequality, and misunderstanding the meaning of `\+/1`.

Comment: I was just trying to say that knowing what `=` does might help explain the cause of the mistake. `dif/2` is about how to avoid the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The `(=)/2` means *unification*, not equality, and a variable *can* unify with anything, by definition.

Then, when you pass an unbound variable to different_fail/2, its first goal will fail, since the unification is actually performed, and then immediately undone by the negation...

I don't agree fully with the answer by mat... I think that in Prolog you cannot avoid to understand the operational semantic...