# Negated possibilities in Prolog

Tags: prolog

This is a somewhat silly example but I'm trying to keep the concept pretty basic for better understanding. Say I have the following unary relations:

```
person(steve). 
person(joe). 

fruit(apples).
fruit(pears).
fruit(mangos).
```

And the following binary relations:

```
eats(steve, apples).
eats(steve, pears).
eats(joe, mangos).
```

I know that querying `eats(steve, F).` will return all the fruit that steve eats (apples and pears). My problem is that I want to get all of the fruits that Steve *doesn't* eat. I know that this: `\+eats(steve,F)` will just return "no" because F can't be bound to an infinite number of possibilities, however I would like it to return mangos, as that's the only existing fruit possibility that steve doesn't eat. Is there a way to write this that would produce the desired result?

I tried this but no luck here either: `\+eats(steve,F), fruit(F).`

If a better title is appropriate for this question I would appreciate any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prolog provides only a very crude form of negation, in fact, `(\+)/1` means simply "not provable at this point in time of the execution". So you have to take into account the exact moment when `(\+)/1` is executed. In your particular case, there is an easy way out:

```
fruit(F), \+eats(steve,F).
```

In the general case, however, this is far from being fixed easily. Think of `\+ X = Y`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523608/what-is-the-logical-not-in-prolog/8523825#8523825).

Another issue is that negation, even if used properly, will introduce *non-monotonic* properties into your program: By adding further facts for `eats/2` less might be deduced. So unless you really want this (as in this example where it does make sense), *avoid the construct*.

Comment: Thank you for your response. In a basic example like this, would it be possible to store this logic in a rule and then call that rule? For instance, "doesnt_eat(P) :- fruit(F), \+eats(P,F)." Then if I call it with "doesn't_eat(steve).", it just returns true rather than the desired "mangos."

Comment: You would need `doesnt_eat(P,F) :- ...`. If you have a one-argument relation as you suggest, the name `person_that_does_not_eat_some_fruit/1` would be more appropriate.

Comment: And: ideally, your definition would be `doesnt_eat(P, F) :- person(P), fruit(F), \+eats(P,F).` so you can ask "Who does not eat mango?": `doesnt_eat(P,mango)`