# What does `\+` signify as an operator in prolog?

Tags: syntax, prolog

I have encountered the symbol `\+` in prolog and am not sure as to what it signifies. I have gone through the prolog documentation and am either not being too resourceful or have not really noticed it.

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8523825/772868)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a non-provable operator. See this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog#Negation) to learn more. Basically, it's true if the argument is not provable.

Comment: Genuinely surprised Wikipedia has my answer! But thank you - This answers my question.